# Gather all the unique values from 2 columns into a new column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe  which includes all the nodes' connections in a network and I want to create a new dataframe named 'nodes' with all the unique nodes. Im trying to do something like

```
eids<-as.factor(d$from)
mids<-as.factor(d$to)
nodes<-data.frame(c(eids,mids))
nodes<-unique(nodes)
```

but when I try to create the graph I get:`Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame` which means that part of my data is missed with this method. My dataset is quite large so I put a toy dataset here.

```
from<-c(2,3,4,3,1,2)
to<-c(8,8,7,5,6,5)
d<-data.frame(from,to)
```

Comment: What is the expected output of your toy dataset?

Comment: a column with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. but with the way I do it I miss data in my actual dataset so Im looking for another way.

Comment: `as.factor(unique(c(as.character(from), as.character(to))))`

Comment: try `unique(stack(d)[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to solve your question, you can use `unique(stack(d)[1])` to get a data frame with one column with values 1 to 8.

---

Here I explain why your code doesn't work. Using `c()` to combine objects of factor class is dangerous. You can try the following example:

```
(x <- factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
# [1] A B C D
# Levels: A B C D

(y <- factor(c("E", "F", "G", "H")))
# [1] E F G H
# Levels: E F G H

c(x, y)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Actually, the factor object is based on numeric data, not character. You can strip away its class and find that it belongs to a numeric vector with an attribute named `levels`:

```
unclass(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

The numeric part means the **indices** of levels. A factor object actually works like recording the indices of its levels.